# matlab autocorrelation in loop tracing max value and lag

Tags: matlab

i have a mono signal and from it i want to extract some features. In particularly for a sliding window of 128 samples with 50% overlapping i need to extract for each window 255 values with xcorr function and then find the max value and the lag of that window.I have tried to wrote a code but without success, maybe someone could point me to the wright direction? , any advice appreciated, thanks in advance.

here is my code:

```
x=rand(1,10000); 
N=length(x);%length of signal
win1=128;  %length of autocorrelation window
win_num=floor((N/win1)*2-1); %number of windows

for L=1:win1/2:win_num % 50% overlapping - 64 samples for 128 window
    for m=1:128 %samples of each window for each frame
        [cmax(L,m),lag(L,m)]=max(xcorr(x(L:m+win1:N),x(L:m+win1:N)));
    end
end
```

Comment: Could you post small sample input (i.e.the values of x) and the desired output, please?

Comment: the signal x can be random like x=rand(1,2000); the output should be a matrix that has [window number L, samples in that window m], and another one matrix should be [L , lags the lags where are the max values]

Comment: Could you update the question with a complete executable example, please? Define a fixed set of inputs and and define exactly what the output should be. People can the compare their code to your desired output. Don't leave anything hanging. Please read [How To Create An MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly. You have a lot higher change of getting a useful answer if you do.